# [Python][socket][client] connect to server using specific port

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to write a simple socket program to connect to the server using specific port. It works fine for the first time (it sends data using 127.0.0.1:8000 to server (127.0.0.1:6000)). However, when I rerun the code, I get below error:

OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Then after a while, it works again (just once). I think the socket is locked up and needs timeout because I'm not closing/shutdown socket properly but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestion/comment would be greatly appreciated~!

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 6000)

myIP = '127.0.0.1'
myPort = 8000

sock.bind((myIP,myPort))
sock.connect(server_address)

msg = 'test'
sock.sendall(msg)

sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
sock.close()
```

Comment: Don't call `bind` on the client side.

Comment: then how do I send on specific port? The system requires the client to send on specific port....so I have to specify a client port...

Comment: That's not normal operation of a TCP client/server connection.  A port is assigned when you connect.

Comment: yes, it's not. But I don't have control over our server and looks like our server is only accepting from specific client port

Comment: Then you get to live with the problems.  A connection is uniquely identified by (client ip, client port, dest ip, dest port, protocol) so if you force a client port to always be the same instead of letting the system choose an available port it may not be available.

Comment: Also, once you've run one connection and closed it, the TCP state machine still maintains the connection in  `TIME_WAIT` state for some period of time, so the port isn't available immediately.  You can see this with a monitoring program like [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview)

Comment: is there any other way to assign client port besides using bind? or a way to monitor status of TIME_WAIT?

Comment: `bind` is the API.  Note forcing a port means you can have two connections from the same IP as well, and the port won't be available until `TIME_WAIT` state expires.

Comment: *...and looks like our server is only accepting from specific client port...* It's possible but I doubt it. Have you tried simply removing the `bind()` call altogether?

Comment: yes, unfortunately, when bind() is removed, port is randomly assigned at TX time.